# Call Unity Android Method from javascript and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am developing an **android app using unity game-engine** that require some function calling from JavaScript(A website which also open in a mobile browser) and vice-versa. Like a JavaScript/html will open my app. Then it can order an object in my APK (the player or camera) to go at specific position in a 3D environment. Or conversely the app can call the JavaScript method at the Website which is open in the mobile browser on the same device.

I am able to successfully open my unity based APK from a web-page using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598189/how-to-start-unity3d-app-from-mobile-browser/31488944?noredirect=1#comment98012981_31488944) at Stackoverflow (Thanks to @romaroma) but I don't have any idea that how to do other stuff.

It seems that first I have to write a function in unity, then call that function from java and then that function will be called by the JavaScript

**JavaScript code call->java method->C# method**

Edit:
Thanks to @Mahdi-Malv comment, i found that how Java to C# and C# to Java Calling can work (not tested but seems it will work)

> If you want to call a c# from java, use UnitySendMessage() function.
>   If you want to call java from c#, use AndroidJavaObject and
>   AndroidJavaClass

Now the answer is still incomplete that how do my andriod app will communicate with a web page (javascript).

Comment: Do you want to call a c# method from java? Where is that java code? In a jar library or something?

Comment: I want to call on both ways. I have exported my unity project with gradle in andriod studio.

Comment: I am just importing my project to android( believe me i don't know how android works) but most probably it will be .java file.

Comment: If you want to call a c# from java, use `UnitySendMessage()` function. If you want to call java from c#, use `AndroidJavaObject` and `AndroidJavaClass`

Comment: Thanks, it will be very helpful. But what about the first step? How do i call my function from a webpage?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about that.

Comment: Do you load a web page from your app?

Comment: No, it can be open at anytime.

Comment: The Android intent you added makes it possible to add links on webpages that will launch your Unity app. In the link you can add ~1KB data, but you cannot interactively communicate directly between Browser <-> Unity app. If you program some server logic and add an ID in your custom schema link, you can communicate as such: Server -> App with link -> launch Unity app -> App parses ID -> sends/receives messages tagged with ID using HTTP calls

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for serverless method.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the methods which are written in javascript from Android native code by below line.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:<method_name>(<parameters_if_any>)");

// for e.g. javascript:populateScanResult('" + contents + "');
```

Thanks!

Comment: which JavaScript, it is using?

Comment: Not using javascript, it is the code to use already written code (JS) in native android (Java).